# Reporting authority when working under a contract agreement

Tags: contractors, contracting

I arrived at my current position on being placed with the client through a third party staffing firm. The position as stated in the contract I signed is a contractual position with the prospect of full time after a certain set number of months. During this contract period, who is my reporting authority as I currently have a question regarding compensation along with a question regarding the project that I am working on. I am confused as to what the reporting hierarchy is when there is an intermediary between the client and the employee (myself).

On one hand, I am working directly with the client who knows directly the daily operations of the firm. On the other hand, I was placed here through the agency. **What is the appropriate channel to go through in this instance?**

Comment: Who do you think is paying you?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan believe it is the staffing firm. I am a bit confused on this matter though

Comment: The staffing firm cuts your checks, so that's where you go to ask about your compensation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently in a similar situation as you are (I am a Software developer on a contract).  I am on a long term contract with the possibility of converting to a full time employee.

I am paid through the contracting company so any matters of pay, health care, paid time off go through the contracting company.  Any thing related to projects go through my "Manager" at the company I am assigned to.

Time off has to be coordinated with the company I am assigned to so they know what is going on and with my contracting company so I can get paid for it (if it is in my contract, I have had both PTO and no PTO at various firms).

All in all the best way to look at your situation is your HR department is the contracting company and your direct supervisor is the manager where you are placed.

Also, as a secondary note, always keep your resume up to date.  As a contractor it is very easy to terminate your contract and the company does not have to worry about actually firing some one.  Has happened to me several times when budgets were tight.